# How to push the data with specific status set?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a config.ts file with following content:

```
export const keyOrders: {} = {
    "aa": { active: true, order: 0 },
    "bb": { active: true, order: 1 },
    "cc": { active: true, order: 2 },
    "dd": { active: true, order: 3 },
    "ee": { active: false, order: 4 },
    "ff": { active: true, order: 5 }
};
```

I am trying to push to array if active is only true. I have tried following code which is pushing key if active is true but if active is false then it is returning "undefined"

```
public keys = [];
public keyOrders = keyOrders;

ngOnInit() {
     this.keys = Object.entries(this.keyOrders).map((a: any) => {
            if(a[1].active == 'true') {
                return a[0];
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) followed by [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

If you want to sort the items based on their `order` property, use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) before `map`.

`filter` will only keep items passing the predicate, in this case a truthy `active` property. Then `map` will map this array to the keys.

In your case, using `map` will give you an array of the same length, you must filter it first.

```
type Order = { active: boolean, order: number };

const keyOrders: { [key: string]: Order } = {
  "aa": { active: true, order: 0 },
  "bb": { active: true, order: 1 },
  "cc": { active: true, order: 2 },
  "dd": { active: true, order: 3 },
  "ee": { active: false, order: 4 },
  "ff": { active: true, order: 5 }
}

this.keys = Object.entries(this.keyOrders)
  .filter(([_, val]) => val.active)
  .sort((a, b) => a[1].order - b[1].order)
  .map(([key, _]) => key);
```

For the types to work out, `Object.entries()` must be recognized by Typescript, for this, add `"lib": [ "es2017.object" ]` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Here is a JavaScript demo (types stripped):

```js
const keyOrders = {
    "aa": { active: true, order: 0 },
    "bb": { active: true, order: 1 },
    "cc": { active: true, order: 2 },
    "dd": { active: true, order: 3 },
    "ee": { active: false, order: 4 },
    "ff": { active: true, order: 5 }
};

const keys = Object.entries(keyOrders)
  .filter(([_, val]) => val.active)
  .sort((a, b) => a[1].order - b[1].order)
  .map(([key, _]) => key);

console.log(keys);
```

Comment: your solution works in snippet but in my case I get Property 'active' does not exist on type '{}'.ts error and I have updated question now, which requires to order the result based on order value

Comment: @nas, I fixed the types in the example, your problem is probably that Object.entries() is not recognized, I also added the sorting. Hope it helps